# horizontal scrollbar appears when not needed (chrome only)

Tags: html, google-chrome, width, scrollbar

On my page horizontal scrollbar appears even, if it should not. The problem appears only in Chrome.

http://megacennik.com/start.html?idHurtownia=13

It looks, like banners on right even, if they have width 120px; overflow:hidden; are much wider, than they should. 
Anyone have idea what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Use `float:left` and `float:right` property instead of `position: relative; left: 882px;`

in your:

`<div style="position:relative;left:882px; height:0px; overflow:visible;">`

Also for finding and solving your problems you can use **Inspect Element** in right click menu and change the valeus of each element for better sense.

Good luck :)

Comment: I know about inspect element, but acording to it, there is nothing on the right, it does not select even <body> or <html>.  

Also, floats are not good for me, because i want main part of page to be in center, not whole page (main page + banners), so banners must be right, so if someone have small screen, banners will be cut, not both banners and main page.